# Double tap in table view cell should come before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to catch a double tap in a table view cell. But if the user taps only once, then perform the  `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to disable the selection from the table, and add 2 tap gestures. One that needs to taps to be fired and the other just one. This last one is your didSelectRowAtIndex. With this approach you would have to manage the selected cell, indexPath, etc if you need to.